# Return COUNT rows of two SELECT related by UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I want to return the number of rows with columns from two Tables related by UNION.
I wrote this query

```
SELECT(
      (SELECT * FROM(
       (SELECT
        ID_COMPTE,
        TITLE,
        LINK,
        DATE_CREAT,
        DATE_MODIF,
        'TF1' AS "TYPE_FICHIER",
        case when DATE_MODIF is null then DATE_CREAT else DATE_MODIF end as LAST_UPDATE FROM FIRST_TABLE FFF where ID_COMPTE= 11111111)

        UNION

        (SELECT
        ID_COMPTE,
        TITLE,
        LINK,
        DATE_CREAT,
        DATE_MODIF,
        'TF2' AS "TYPE_FICHIER",
        case when DATE_MODIF is null then DATE_CREAT else DATE_MODIF end as LAST_UPDATE FROM SECOND_TABLE SSS where ID_COMPTE= 11111111)
        order by LAST_UPDATE desc
        ) parentSelect WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 2)), count(firstSelect) FROM firstSelect;
```

The purpose is to return the the last two rows with the count of all the rows of Table 1 and Table 2.
The query without the count works fine it's just the count that cause problem, I don't know how to insert it.
I tried also to use count() for each SELECT and SUM in the parent SELECT but it doesn't work.

Comment: One would note that the union eliminates duplicates.  If you need the duplicates you could consider using a UNION ALL

Comment: Don't make us to guess your final  output that you want to see. Show some sample rows from the table and desired output.Remember, post it in **text** format only.

Answer (score 1):

This concept should work for you.   Basically you select the data you want in the with clause.  Then in the main select, you select your data, and the count.

```
WITH
base AS
(
    SELECT 'TEST1' DATA FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'TEST2' DATA FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TEST3' DATA FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base) AS KOUNT, base.*
FROM base
;
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I tried it but it doesn't work. If I do SELECT (COUNT(*) FROM base AS KOUNT), base.* FROM base; it return 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis". and If I do SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base AS KOUNT, base.* FROM base;   it returns 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: As you are using Oracle, I made you a working example

Answer (score 0):

You can use #Temp ( TempTable ).
Insert or manupulate the rows in it which you want to have and finally return it from stored procedure.